# "Ambiguous Reference To" Error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Good Afternoon,

Im attempting to code a Music Play Application in which I am trying to implement some Open Source Code entitled "STK Audio Player" which is coded in Objective C.

When attempting to call a Method from the imported Source, I receive the following compile error.

"Ambiguous Reference To Member Play"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer = STKAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let songToPlay:String = "http://themarketshop.com/beats/fatbeat.mp3"

    STKAudioPlayer.play(songToPlay)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

From The Open Source

```
/// Plays an item from the given URL string (all pending queued items are removed).
/// The NSString is used as the queue item ID
-(void) play:(NSString*)urlString;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`play` is an instance (`-`) method, so use the instance:

```
audioPlayer.play(songToPlay)
```

and do not annotate literal strings as `String`. Everybody including the compiler can see what it is.